# Error generating JWT token during ASP.NET Core Web API authorization

Tags: c#, jwt, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Web API project through which I register and log in. During authorization, where I should get a token, an error appears:
`An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.  System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions' threw an exception.    System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Json.JsonConvert' from assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'`

Token generation code:

```
using ASFT.Auth.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ASFT.Auth.Services
{
    public class TokenService : ITokenService
    {
        public string GenerateAccessToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
        {
            var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(AuthOptions.Key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: AuthOptions.Issuer,
                audience: AuthOptions.Audience,
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(48),
                signingCredentials: signinCredentials);

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR5CR.jpg) is on this line - `return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);`

Connected packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.11">
   <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
   <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets></PackageReference>
```

Expected status 200 with token and refresh token in the response body.

Comment: Looks like a Json package error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you should probably include:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.0.0" />
```

in your `.csproj`. Make sure that the `version` value is correct, you're going to want it to match the requirements from your other NuGet packages.

If this doesn't work, this may be an issue caused by the runtime attempting to remove assemblies that it believes that the runtime already has and are being duplicated in your project.

Try adding this to your `.csproj` file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can find a more detailed description and explanation of the issue [here.](https://bryanknox.github.io/2022/07/15/functionsskipcleanoutput-and-functionspreserveddependencies.html)

Comment: I added this line, but the error remains the same ((

Comment: Check my edit to the answer. Once you’ve added the package, do a clean and rebuild.

Comment: Thank you!! I connected System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version 7.0.0 (latest) :)

Comment: In my case, I didn't find the package `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` in version `7.0.11`. Seems like 7.0.0 is the lasted.

Answer (score 18):

It fixed for me by adding this package:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.1" />
```

I used from comment of [@springy76](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098132/error-generating-jwt-token-during-asp-net-core-web-api-authorization/77193400#comment136008891_77133355).

Comment: I must add two packages: "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" and "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt"

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by downgrading 'System.IdentityModel.Token.Jwt' from 7.0.0 to 6.32.3. It seems 7.0.0 is not compatible with other IdentityModel packages.

Comment: This is a [major release and there are some breaking changes](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/IdentityModel-7x). You probably need to update your code, and if you use other packages that depend on IdentityModel you need to wait for those to support the 7.x version as well.

Comment: @EirikH in my case it is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` 7.0.11 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/7.0.11#dependencies-body-tab which "loads" an old 6.x version of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect` which in turn seems to use an (INTERNAL!) JsonObjectAttribute class which no longer exists in `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` 7.0.11. Adding `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.0" />` solved it for me

Comment: @springy76 you're a lifesaver. I've been scratching my head for a few hours yesterday / today (and came across this post yesterday) but this explicit package reference solved it. Honestly, you should post this as an answer to the question itself - it's a better solution than a package downgrade, IMO.

Comment: Agree with Kurtis Jungersen

@springy76, your comment deserves better visibility