# JwtSecurityToken.WriteToken causes "The type initializer for 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions' threw an exception."

Tags: json.net, identitymodel

The following code gives me this error: `The type initializer for 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions' threw an exception.`

```
handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
tokenStringEngineer = handler.WriteToken(token); // this line causes the error
```

InnerException gives details on the error:

```
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload.SerializeToJson()
 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload.Base64UrlEncode()
 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SecurityToken token)
 at my-file.cs:line 519
```

Before that, I had issues with nuget packages, specially `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`

See my previous question here: [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens - problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77431196/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-identitymodel-tokens-problem)

Now, with that installed, I get this new error.

I found that the version of `Newtonsoft.Json` could affect it, so I tried versions 10 to 13, but the error remains. Other suggestions I found did not solve my issue.

So I ask here, any ideas what I can try?

It is a solution with 3 projects, where only one project uses the JSON and Token functions.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the package `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`

I found the solution by searching more and found this:

[Error generating JWT token during ASP.NET Core Web API authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098132/error-generating-jwt-token-during-asp-net-core-web-api-authorization)

It works now